# Actual and Argument Lists Differ in Length

Tags: java, oop

I have this OOP program for my project in which I can't see why it's having an error.

This program is like a voting system, but just simply uses inputs from the keyboard. But before that, I'd like to show previous voters, and then, the candidates and their ranking, using `Voter vote = new Voter("String here");` and `Candidates cand = new Candidates("String");` respectively.

No matter how I review my codes again, I still have the same error. I am a newbie in Java, and it would help if someone could explain and answer me at the same time. And if anyone sees errors other than I stated, it'll be great. Thanks!

My Codes,

The candidate class:

```
    public class Candidates
{
    public String candName;
    private int position;
    private int totalVotes;

    public void Candidate (String candName, int position, int totalVotes)
    {
        this.candName = candName;
        this.position = position;
        this.totalVotes = totalVotes;
    }

    public void setDetails (String candName, int position, int totalVotes)
    {
        this.candName = candName;
        this.position = position;
        this.totalVotes = totalVotes;
    }

    public String getCandName()
    {
        return candName;
    }

    public int getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

    public int getTotalVotes()
    {
        return totalVotes;
    }
}
```

The voter class:

```
    public class Voter
{
    private String name;
    private int votNum;
    private int precint;

    public Voter(String name, int votNum, int precint, double bDay)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.votNum = votNum;
        this.precint = precint;
    }

    public void setDetails(String name, int votNum, int precint)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.votNum = votNum;
        this.precint = precint;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getVotNum()
    {
        return votNum;
    }

    public int getPrecint()
    {
        return precint;
    }


    public Voter toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(name).append(" ");
        sb.append(votNum).append(" ");
        sb.append(precint).append(" ");
         sb.append("Voter's Name: ").append(" ");
         sb.append("Voter's ID number: ").append(" ");
         sb.append("Precint: ").append(" ");
         return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The main class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class voteDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Previous voter's info: ");
        Voter vot1 = new Voter("Name1", 131, 01);
        Voter vot2= new Voter("Name2", 265, 02);
        Voter vot3= new Voter("Name3", 343, 01);
    System.out.println(vot1);
    System.out.println(vot2);
    System.out.println(vot3);

    System.out.println("The Candidates: ");
        Candidates cand1  = new Candidates("Candidate1", 1, 19000);
        Candidates cand2 = new Candidates("Candidate2" , 2, 17000);
        Candidates cand3 = new Candidates("Candidate3", 3, 12000);
    System.out.println(cand1);
    System.out.println(cand2);
    System.out.println(cand3);

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Voter's Name: ");
        String name = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Voter's ID: ");
        int votNum = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Precint: ");
        int precint = kb.nextInt();

        do
        {
            System.out.println("\n\nSelect Candidate for Senator:");
            System.out.println("1 - Choice1");
            System.out.println("2 - Choice2");
            System.out.println("3 - Choice3");
            System.out.println("4 - Choice4");
        System.out.println("5 - Choice5");
        System.out.print("\nEnter choice: ");

            choice = kb.nextInt();

           switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                        System.out.println("Voter ID: " + votNum);
                        System.out.println("Precint No.: " + precint);
                        System.out.println("Senator of choice: Choice1");
                        break;
                case 2:
                        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                        System.out.println("Voter ID: " + votNum);
                        System.out.println("Precint No.: " + precint);
                        System.out.println("Senator of choice: Choice2");
                        break;
                case 3:
                        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                        System.out.println("Voter ID: " + votNum);
                        System.out.println("Precint No.: " + precint);
                        System.out.println("Senator of choice: Choice3");
                        break;
                case 4:
                        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                        System.out.println("Voter ID: " + votNum);
                        System.out.println("Precint No.: " + precint);
                        System.out.println("Senator of choice: Choice4");
                        break;
                case 5:
                        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                        System.out.println("Voter ID: " + votNum);
                        System.out.println("Precint No.: " + precint);
                        System.out.println("Senator of choice: Choice5");
                        break;

                default:
                        System.out.println("Error. Review your entries.");
                        break;
            }
        } while (choice != 5 );

    System.out.println("Press Enter to confirm.");

    }
    }
```

The error that I get:

> required: String,int,int,double  found: String,int,int
>    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>    on lines 7, 8, 9 and 15, 16, 17 on my main class.
>
> voteDemo.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
>                         choice = kb.nextInt();
>    on my main class

Comment: What's the problem? What does the error message say?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Consider [reducing this to a short example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) that shows the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, it means that you have a method call that requires N arguments, but you have given it the wrong number of arguments; e.g.

```
    public void setFoo(int arg) { ... }

    // using it correctly
    setFoo(24);

    // using it incorrectly
    setFoo();                     // compilation error - wrong number of args
    setFoo(42, 43);               // compilation error - wrong number of args
```

---

You can get the same thing with a constructor and `new` ... as you have done.

```
public Voter(String name, int votNum, int precint, double bDay)

Voter vot1 = new Voter("Name1", 131, 01);
```

See?

You declared it with 4 arguments, and tried to use it with 3.

---

And this one ...

> voteDemo.java:47: error: cannot find symbol choice = kb.nextInt(); on my main class

You haven't declared `choice`.  You just assigned to a variable that you haven't declared.  Can't do that in Java.  Every variable must be explicitly declared.

---

While I have your attention, it is usually **a bad idea** to put leading zeros on a Java numeric literal.  Why?  Because leading zeros tell the Java compiler that you are using octal not decimal.  So `011` *actually* means nine, not eleven!  Don't use leading zeros unless you *mean* to write your numbers in octal.

Comment: Sorry, I may have overseen that. But thanks, I have lesser errors now.